# C++ POCO command line processing

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I am trying to create a small application using Poco::Util::Application, as it gives you a few things, such as configuration and a logger, right out of the gate. One of the things it also gives you is a config() member, which returns a LayeredConfiguration object. According to the documentation, you can use methods such as setString and getString.

However, I am stuck on using this config part when parsing command line arguments. The problem seems to have something to do with variable scope. If I use a callback function and set the parameter in the this->config() object, the value doesn't "stick". Once it returns to main(), the value will be reset to the default.

The following is a minimal example:

```
#include <Poco/Util/Application.h>

#include <Poco/Util/Option.h>
#include <Poco/Util/OptionSet.h>
#include <Poco/Util/OptionCallback.h>

#include <iostream>

class OptionExample : public Poco::Util::Application
{
protected:
    void initialize(Poco::Util::Application& application){
        this->config().setString("optionval", "defaultoption");
        this->loadConfiguration();
        Poco::Util::Application::initialize(application);
    }

    void uninitialize(){
        Poco::Util::Application::uninitialize();
    }

    void defineOptions(Poco::Util::OptionSet& optionSet) {
        Poco::Util::Application::defineOptions(optionSet);

        optionSet.addOption(
                Poco::Util::Option("optionval", "", "Some value")
                        .required(false)
                        .repeatable(true)
                        .argument("<the value>", true)
                        .callback(Poco::Util::OptionCallback<OptionExample>(this, &OptionExample::handleMyOpt))
        );
    }

    void handleMyOpt(const std::string &name, const std::string &value) {
        std::cout << "Setting option " << name << " to " << value << std::endl;
        this->config().setString(name, value);
        std::cout << "The option is now " << this->config().getString(name) << std::endl;
    }

    int main(const std::vector<std::string> &arguments) {
        std::cout << "We are now in main. Option is " << this->config().getString("optionval") << std::endl;
    }
};

POCO_APP_MAIN(OptionExample)
```

Running it without command line arguments works as expected:

> $ ./Minimal
> We are now in main. Option is defaultoption

Running it with the command line arguments, shows that the option gets set. However, after get'ting the option from main(), it will have been reset to the default.

> $ ./Minimal --optionval=mystring
>
> Setting option optionval to mystring
>
> The option is now mystring
>
> We are now in main. Option is defaultoption

As I said, I'm expecting variable scope is killing me somewhere here. But, I've already tried variations such as

```
Poco::Util::Application &application = Poco::Util::Application::instance();
std::cout << application.config().getString("optionval");
```

which yields identical results.

The documentation for POCO is relatively extensive. There are examples in the source code on github, but this particular thing seems to be missing.

Can somebody enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to have been pretty easy.

Apparently, the error only appears when the config().setString() call is done in initialize().

By moving the call to defineOptions(), the default value works as expected.